# Does the 2022-04-04 Raspberry PI OS update contain the new Paragon NTFS support

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, ntfs

The release notes show Linux kernel 5.15.30 which is supposed to contain the new Paragon NTFS module, but after updating I see no performance improvement over the old NTFS-3g support.
Perhaps there's additional configuration steps I need to follow?

Answer (score 2):

It worked out-of-the-box for me (although I'm testing on kernel 5.15.76 / RaspiOS release 2022-09-22).
You might need to specify `mount -t ntfs3`, if it does not default to it.
Testing with an external USB HDD, its still not blazing fast, but there is a definite improvement:

##### ntfs3 (new Paragon NTFS)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount -t ntfs3 /dev/sda1 hdd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mount
[...]
/dev/sda1 on /home/pi/hdd type ntfs3 (rw,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,iocharset=utf8)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd hdd/
pi@raspberrypi:~/hdd $ dd if=/dev/zero of=write.test bs=100M count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 4.32912 s, 24.2 MB/s
pi@raspberrypi:~/hdd $ cd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo umount hdd
```

Result: `24.2 MB/s`

##### ntfs-3g

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 hdd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mount
[...]
/dev/sda1 on /home/pi/hdd type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd hdd/
pi@raspberrypi:~/hdd $ dd if=/dev/zero of=write.test bs=100M count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 14.1101 s, 7.4 MB/s
pi@raspberrypi:~/hdd $ cd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo umount hdd
```

Result: `7.4 MB/s`

##### ntfs-3g -o big_writes

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o big_writes /dev/sda1 hdd
pi@raspberrypi:~/hdd $ mount
[...]
/dev/sda1 on /home/pi/hdd type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd hdd/
pi@raspberrypi:~/hdd $ dd if=/dev/zero of=write.test bs=100M count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 7.73435 s, 13.6 MB/s
pi@raspberrypi:~/hdd $ cd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo umount hdd
```

Result: `13.6 MB/s`

---

##### Version Info

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.76-v8+ #1597 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 4 12:16:41 GMT 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

**Note:** This test was done on a RPi 3, so newer Pis (3+, 4) might further benefit from the better USB controllers and USB 3.0.

Comment: I've been away for a while so I'm pleased to see your very thorough response. I'll try this and report back.

Comment: It took me a while, but I finally was able to get version 5.15.84-v7l+ installed ... I don't see much of a performance improvement but that may be a function of samba ... which is needed to access my files from the Windows PC (my main usage ... i use RaspPi as a file server).